# Exceeding 10 nested forwards?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My project requires multiple payment gateways, so I set up a module per payment gateway and bound the appropriate payment gateway to the account that was using it. I then placed all payment code within the appropriate module controller. All gateways implement the same interface to ensure functions exist.

I am now running a nightly cron to charge payments against each account. The issue I'm getting is that in order to get the appropriate controller to run, I am using the following code inside a `foreach` loop:

```
$response = $this->forward()->dispatch(sprintf('PaymentGateway\%s\Controller\Index', ucwords($pg->code)), $params);
```

where `$pg->code` is the payment gateway assigned to the account.

At the moment I have two payment gateways (this will be going up in the near future) with about 20 test payments to be processed each. When I run the cron command I am getting the error:

> Circular forwarding detected: greater than 10 nested forwards

In this scenario I need it to run 40 times, but that will go up in the future as more payment gateways are added and more transactions are queued.

In terms of a solution, I am looking to either

- disable this check for the purposes of my cron or,
- find an alternative to `$this->forward()->dispatch(...);` that will still allow me to call a different controller multiple times with custom parameters.

The alternative is that I pass in all transactions to each respective payment gateway and only call `$this->forward()->dispatch()` once per gateway, but I'll hit this issue again when I get to ten payment gateways.

Comment: Why do you have a transaction dispatch dispatch the next transaction? That seems completely counter intuitive. Why are you not looping the transactions to be executed. In that loop you dispatch the transaction within a try/catch to ensure that the loop continues, even if a single transaction fails. Even better would be to do such a thing multithreaded (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php, https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/ (chapter Recycling Threads))

Comment: That is what I'm doing. I have a loop of transactions, each transaction being dispatched to the payment gateway that charges the account for the transaction amount. This is inside a try/catch block where the exceptions are logged and, outside the loop, emailed to me for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forward` controller plugin allows you to set the maximum number of nested forwards.

Before my loop I set the max number of nested forwards to the number of items I was going to loop through:

```
$this->forward()->setMaxNestedForwards(count($transactions));
```

Comment: Is this an answer or additional info? It reads as additional information.

Comment: This is the answer. Need to wait another day before I can accept it.